# How to load suggestions dynamically, while user typing text

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying to achieve the following result: I intend using TokenEdit from Devexpress. The goal is to make suggestions of available tokens while user is typing. The available tokens are stored in Db.

So, I have at least two issues.

The first one: I intend to handle KeyDown event. Count 3 letters and to make query to Db. Is my approach good or are there other more efficient approaches?

The second one: I can't get typing text in the KeyDown event. For instance, the EditValue and EditText properties contain already validated and accepted tokens. How can I get the typed text?

Comment: Why worry about efficiency if you haven't even measured the time? Implement it and see how fast it is. If it's too slow, come back and ask. If it's fast, you don't have a problem and no need to ask a question.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: During Keydown, the key has not been processed yet.  That's why there is also a KeyPress event or TextChanged or ...

Comment: @ThomasWeller,I can't implement any approach because I don't know how to get the text typed by the user. The TokenEdit control has two obvious properties - EditValue and Edittext. When you see their names, you expect them to store the text that the user is currently typing. Actually, they store tokens that have already been validated and accepted. I did the debug and found where it stores, but it stores in the private class. That's why I'm asking for help, in the hope that someone solved this issue.

Comment: As for the second question, it seems there is no way except keeping track of the input yourself.

Comment: Just quickly commenting that, if you want to have a simple go-to alternative to deal with what is being currently inputted, you should focus on KeyUp rather than on KeyDown. Or, of course, on other options as already suggested by @ThomasWeller